# Site-wide Inherited Resources behavior Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, inherited-resources

I'm trying to develop some conventions behind our controller responses.  One of my conventions is:

> > On successful `create`, if the request is XHR, render @the_object

I can't see anything that allows me to do this across the board.  Currently I'm doing this:

```
def create
  create! do |success, failure|
    success.html {
      render @the_object if request.xhr?
    }
  end
end
```

It's obviously not ideal to have to do this for each controller.  Does anyone know if I can create site-wide configurable responses?

Comment: create a method in your application controller to do this ?

Comment: haven't tried that... but inherited_resources inherits from ApplicationController, so won't its methods override this?

Answer (score 0):

May be can help you :

```
# coding: utf-8
class CatsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authorize_admin
    inherit_resources #Permet d'utiliser la gem inherit ressources
    def create
        create!(:notice => "Catégorie ajouté avec succès") { {:controller => 'cats' }}
    end
end
```

Write your method in the ApplicationController and ... :)
Or tell me if i'm wrong, i'm not too good in english and beginner in rails